# Javascript - Plugin should not affect all select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use a JQuery/Javascript plugin which changes select boxes with:

```
$('select').multipleSelect();
```

The select boxes look like:

```
<select multiple=\"multiple\">\r\n" + 
<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"1\">January</option> 
<option value=\"2\">December</option>
<option value=\"3\">December2</option>
</select>
```

The probem is that it changes all select boxes on the site but it should change one select box only.

How to do it?

Comment: have you tried changing the jquery selector from $('select') to $('select#id')??  where the 2nd selector is the one you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the `select` you want to select, a class, and then call the plugin on it

```
<select class="selectMe" multiple="multiple">
   <option selected="selected" value="1">January</option> 
   <option value="2">December</option>
   <option value="3">December2</option>
</select>
```

And then in jQuery

```
$('select.selectMe').multipleSelect();
```

You need not define an actual class in CSS, though you can, if you want. From now on, just add class `selectMe` to the `<select>` that you want the plugin to be called upon.

Comment: @user3688653 you're most welcome and glad to have helped you :)